# Align columns vertically in a grid so that it fills empty space

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, slds-grid

I need to fill empty spaces of columns height wise but it is not filling of its own. Sometimes my one column can be of different height.[image: at]
I have used it like this:

```
<div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap" style="width:1210px;" >
   <div class="slds-size--6-of-12 slds-m-top_x-small">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the lightning web component, try to use lightning-layout to align all items properly.

Comment: It is not working. Same as before.

Comment: Can you share the markup that you are trying. It would be helpful to debug the issue.